# Python - regex - how to find ONLY four letter words?

Tags: python, regex

I am working with a string of text that I want to search through and only find 4 letters words.  It works, except it also finds 4+ letter words as well.

```
import re
test ="hello, how are you doing tonight?"
total = len(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]{3}', text))
print (total)
```

It finds 15, although I am not sure how it found that many. I thought I might have to use \b to pick the beginning and the end of the word, but that didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: show what you tried with `\b`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

`re.findall(r'\b\w{4}\b',text)`

The regex matches:

`\b`, which is a word boundary. 
It matches the beginning or end of a word.

`\w{4}` matches four word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or _).

`\b` is yet another word boundary.

**As a side note, your code contains typos, the second parameter of the re.findall should be the name of your string variable, which is test. Also, your string does not contain any 4 letter words so the suggested code will give the output of 0.

Comment: Yes thank you.  I did notice that after.  I have made the correction and added in the \b as well.  Great !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way without regex:

```
from string import punctuation

s = "hello, how are you doing tonight?"

[i for i in s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', punctuation)).split(' ') if len(i) > 4]

# ['hello', 'doing', 'tonight']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to locate all letters, and then filter based off of length:

```
import re
test ="hello, how are you doing tonight?"
final_words = list(filter(lambda x:len(x) == 4, re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', test)))
```